# How does a food shortage work on an entire planet?

Tags: star-wars

In a Star Wars Young Adult novel, *Queen's Peril*, shortly before the Battle of Naboo, they apparently have a food shortage due to a bad growing season, and contemplate getting food offworld

> "It had been a long day with the regional
> representatives -there was a projected labor
> shortage for this year's grain harvest, and
> debate was split over whether to bring in
> offworlders to help with the work or to simply
> buy food from off planet and let the grain
> become next season's fertilizer- and they were
> all eager to wrap up."

I know Star Wars treats entire planets like cities, but logic should dictate that an entire terrestrial world (roughly the size of Earth) should be able to get food from another part of the planet. It's like, if my city (NYC) was having a food shortage and we were thinking of asking astronauts on the International Space Station for more food instead of Washington D.C.

What is a good in-universe explanation for this?

Comment: I think given 20 years or so we'll understand what planet-wide food shortages are...  There are definitely things that can affect the entire planetary ecology at once; think nuclear winter or, in a science fictional context, passing through a nebula.

Comment: Doesn't the passage from the book say the problem is a labor shortage? This seems like more of an economic question than an ecological one.

Comment: Pretty much every other planet in our system has a food shortage right now. It's one of the problems when planning a mission to Mars

Comment: @defaultlocale You win the internet for today with that comment. Well done sir/madam/non-binary pronoun

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's really more suited to the World Building SE.

Comment: They've been saying that, @DavidW, with time periods of 5 to 20 years, for at least the last 40 years. The funny thing, is that even though the population keeps growing, and the amount of arable land is reduced (mostly for housing growth), production per acre keeps increasing. That is, at least, until "helpful" government regulations start banning all the things that allow that to happen...

Comment: @FreeMan I'm not talking about population growth, I'm talking about climate change; there have already been large-scale crop losses because of unseasonable heat, unseasonable drought, unseasonable storms... but so far not so bad as to affect global food supply.  (But do note how fast food prices are going up.)  Yet.  Things aren't bad _yet_, but truly we are only just starting this adventure.  In 20 years we'll be more than 2C above historical temperatures and things will be _unpleasant._

Comment: Back in the 70s, there was also an ice age coming by the turn of the century... :shrug: I don't deny science, I just question it with an open mind...

Comment: @FreeMan Back in the 1970s there was no such scientific consensus, just some randos.  In fact there were _already_ people studying the global greenhouse effect, it just hadn't gotten any publicity.  It's undeniable that we _are_ warming, that we're warming _fast_, and COP28 has made it abundantly clear that there is _no_ appetite to actually do anything about it.  IPCC says 1.5C by the 2030s, but we're still _increasing_ the amount of CO2 produced.  We are going to _blow_ by that number.

Comment: @DavidW Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1732/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As presented in the passage quoted from the book, the problem with the grain harvest was a "projected labor shortage". Since this is being brought up at a meeting of "regional representatives", assuming these are representatives from different regions of Naboo, this implies that there just aren't enough agricultural workers in the combined workforce of the planet to harvest all of the grain.

Labor shortages exist within industries [in real-world countries](https://www.uschamber.com/workforce/understanding-americas-labor-shortage-the-most-impacted-industries), so it makes sense that something similar could happen on a planet with a single government that otherwise has plenty of resources. Naboo isn't shown in Canon* to make much use of droid labor, and has a peaceful enough culture not to resort to conscripting its citizens into farm labor, so its leaders' offered solutions—hiring offworlders to harvest the crops, or importing food from other worlds—are reasonable approaches.

We might also speculate that Naboo's citizens have increasingly migrated to its cities over time. After all—[how ya gonna keep 'em down on the farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYflT3h6lCQ), after they've seen [Parrlay](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Parrlay)?

#### Legends notes

*Queen's Peril* is in the Canon continuity, but may have built on previous Legends lore about Naboo. [*The Essential Atlas*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas) describes Naboo as having a population of 4.5 billion, 27% of which is Human, implying that the Human civilization led by Queen Amidala has about 1.2 billion people—less than the largest real-world countries as of 2023. Naboo's exports are also listed as "grains" and "works of art".

*The Royal Naboo civilization in [*Galactic Battlegrounds*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Galactic_Battlegrounds) does make use of [worker droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/PKN-49_worker_droid) for construction, mining, and agricultural tasks. I haven't seen reference to this idea in Canon works, so it may be Legends-only or just a game mechanic.